# Photodiode to op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I need to detect if a monomode fiber loop is intact. To that end, I have a laser diode emitting max. 10 mW (adjustable) at 1310 nm.

At the receiving end, there is a matched photodiode (Laserscom.com PDI-80-2G-K) which gives about 1 mA per mW when I measure directly over the output leads.

The laser diode and the photodiode are inserted in the fiber loop and work as predicted.

The problem to solve is how to use the diode so as to have a relay open when the laser light is lost.

Looking at a commercial simple dusk switch using an op-amp and a BC547 it appears that it might be possible to use the diode instead of the LDR in front of the op-amp provided that the circuit is adapted accordingly regarding resistor values etc.

The diode data are: max. reverse voltage 20 V, operating voltage 3-5 V, responsivity 0,96 mA/mW at 1550 nm (slightly less at 1310 nm).

How could the circuit below be modified to use the photodiode (the LDR has been replaced with the photodiode in the drawing)?

[image: [img]https://i.postimg.cc/SKDg19FR/photodiodesnip.png[/img]]

Comment: I already have the diode which is fitted with monomode fiber pigtails and the necessary SC connectors. It was not easy to find a laser transmitter to connect to the monomode fiber loop. I found one in Byelorussia and it could be delivered with a matched diode. So I restrict the question to circuits with a photodiode input and a relay output

Comment: Do you care about latency , dropout time , hysteresis, drifting levels thermal effects, avoiding supply ripple?  Variation in Tx power levels? Then add to YOUR missing Design Spec.

Comment: unless you define anything else such as above, Murphy's Law may happen to you.  Like an oscillating Relay where the level cuts in and out that quickly burns out due EMI pickup from the relay kickback. Generally rise time in a PD due to diode cct capacitance is dV/dt=I/C  thus turn off fall time is slower yet both depend on thresholds and RC time constant with noise margin and tolerances. It is really simple once you define these levels and times with impedance of signals and noise. List what you know and TBD for the rest.  or dont and just play with it till it seems to work for now. (hmm...)

Comment: Tony, thanks for your warnings. Unfortunately, I lack the knowledge to take what you listed in account. I'll make a protracted test before integrating the circuit in the alarm system.

Comment: Test by Trial and Error without specs?

Answer (score 2):

If you can find a a phototransistor sensitive to 1310nm, you should use that intead of a photodiode here. Photodiodes are required for high sensitivity, high speed, high linearity circuits but also much more TIA circuitry. There's not much point here for your intended purpose. If you use a phototransistor you might be able to use it to drive the relay coil directly but I somewhat doubt it. Instead you can use the phototransistor (in a darlington-like arrangement) to drive another transistor to drive the relay coil.

If you want to fine tune the switching threshold you would need a comparator. By the way, the opamp you posted is being forced into use as a comparator which is not optimal. It should preferably be a comparator with hysteresis or else you might find yourself with unstable behaviour.

Just place the resistor above and the photodiode below, or vice versa across the power rails to match your comparator logic state and use the center node as your input to the comparator. You won't need all that extra stuff in front of the opamp if that's the case.

EDIT: Since you are using a laser with your photodiode, you may be able to use its output directly, as you would a phototransistor, if the laser diode can excite the photodiode enough.

Otherwise you will need to build a transimpedance amplifier (TIA) around it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7rrY6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Still, I see many designs on the web where a photodiode (not a phototransistor or LDR) is used with an opamp and a following transistor to drive the relay. Only I lack the knowledge to design a suitable circuit myself. I know that photodiodes are over qualified for the purpose. I don't need linear response, just on/off. Als, I haven't seen any photo transistors with monomode fiber pigtails and SC connectors. There wouldn't be any market for them.

Comment: @jonasolof Are those designs you saw where a laser directly illuminates a photodiode because if they were not they probably would need a TIA.

Comment: OK, I'll try putting the diode as you suggested. What about the minus side input of the opamp? Should it just float?

Comment: @jonasolof No, use your part of the circuit for that. I was just lazy. To test just wire up the resistor and photodiode with power and illuminate it. See how much voltage output you get. If it turns out you get enough voltage but not current, you can use an NMOS instead of a BJT (for the lower circuit. for top circuit opamp inputs should be quite high impedance already so current shouldn't matter).

Comment: The band gap of silicon devices means they are not sensitive to 1310nm light, they are only good up to ~1000nm. The only devices normally available for 1310nm will be indium gallium arsenide photodiodes.

Comment: @KevinWhite You seem to be implying phototransistor implies silicon but have not made it evident.

Comment: When direct feeding the diode with the laser I get 0.48 volts over a one meg resistor. Don't know if that's enough. BTW; the diode is matched to the laser. It has maximum sensitivity at 1600 nm and about 80 percent of that at 1310. Documentation is provided by the manufacturer Laserscom.

Comment: And it's a InGaAs PIN diode.

Comment: @jonasolof Not enough to drive a BJT or MOSFET directly, but it might be enough if you feed it to your comparator and it can maintain that 0.5V. Try it. Obviously you need a comparator whose common mode input range reaches GND. Then set your comparator threshold at the inverting low like 0.3~0.4V or something maybe. You might need a comparator with input impedance >10MOhm and lower input bias currents than LM324 due to the 1MOhm resistor..

Comment: Now it works using what you said, but due to a misunderstanding I connected the diode plus 1 mohm resistor directly to the positiv input side of the opamp. The positive side of the diode, as measured when fed by the laser thus goes to the positiv input. The other side to ground via the resistor. Thus, I didn't use the diode with a reverse voltage. It now remains to reverse the relay action. The circuit draws 45 mA when the relay is activated (laser light on). When the fiber loop is interrupted, only 0,7 mA is drawn. I'll fix that by inserting a circuit between the opamp and the BC547.

Comment: @jonasolof Why do you need to reverse it? As is, it should already cause the coil drive transistor to conduct when light is detected thus keeping the relay closed as long as their is light. If for some reason you need to reverse it you should be able to just put the diode on the bottom and resistor on top (but then you need an op-amp that whose common mode input can reach the positive rail). Unless I misunderstood what you said.

Comment: We use to use a red light on one end and look in the other, and if we saw a red dot if it was intact. This was in the lab many years ago. For all I know it will still work and is much less costly.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem to solve is how to use the diode so as to have a relay open when the laser light is lost.

Either use a normally-closed relay (a form B relay or the NC contact of a form C relay), or switch the inputs to the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

The photodiode, a InGaAs PIN, is driven by a laser diode at 1310 nm through a monomode fiber loop with about 5 mW power. This gives 0,48 volt out from the diode over a 1 mohm resistor. This is enough to direct feed the LM324 op amp in a modified 7 euro Velleman MK125 dusk relay kit. As it is for an alarm, the relay should be NC. Therefore, the inputs to the opamp have been shifted. When there is light through the fiber, power draw is only 0,7 mA from the 12 volt supply. Power draw when the relay is activated depends on the coil resistance.

The photodiode is not used in the usual reverse voltage mode. This is a crude solution but it works well.

The disadvantage is that the laser diode plus optodiode fitted with fiber pigtails and SC fiber connectors are expensive, about 240 euros plus shipping and VAT. An alternative is to use TP LINK fiber to Ethernet converters such as MC111CS and MC112CS. When the fiber link is intact, a led in each unit provides 1.9 volts over the led. This can be connected to an external circuit, in my case a transistor 2N2222A preamp followed by an optocoupler (TIL111) and a transistor 2N2222A to control the relay.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: If that works, it's more by luck than judgement. It relies on the photodiode modulating bias current of the inverting input of the LM324. For that particular opamp, this might actually work, due to the inputs of the LM324 being PNP transistors, but it would fail with any FET input opamp.